# Upbeat country pop, currently popular among teens (2019), punchy guitar ending

Tags: identify-this-song, country

I was at a pool party several days ago when this song came on, and nearly every one of my classmates knew the words. I couldn't hear it too well, though, so I didn't catch the lyrics, but it sounded fun. I'm really curious to know what the song was, but I don't know who to ask– didn't really know anyone at the party that well. It was probably a country song with a pop vibe, male singer, and really upbeat– may have said something about Saturday, but idk for sure? real good-time party vibes. Sounded modern, and a bunch of teenagers knew it. We're in South Carolina if that helps narrow it down. What I most remember was that it ended on a punchy guitar chord (as opposed to fading out or smth) and EVERYONE in the pool made a noise to punctuate it. I'd be so happy if anyone could tell me what this song was.

Comment: Well if it was popular among teenagers, it could be part of Fallout videogame soundtrack since they use a lot of classic, country songs. You could try *Country Roads* (not modern thou) for example or check other country songs for the Fallout soundtrack.

Answer (score 1):

The most inescapable country pop song of the moment is [Old Town Road](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ysFgElQtjI) by Lil Nas X, with Billy Ray Cyrus.  It was a recent #1 hit, with a male singer and a pop vibe --and people love to sing along with it!

However, it doesn't have the "Saturday" reference or the punchy guitar chord ending.